# Order By doesnt work on Google Spreadsheet API

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I am trying to sort a Google Spreadsheet with the Java API but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. The code I am using is really simple as shown in the [API reference](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#sorting_rows).

```
URL listFeedUrl = new URI(worksheet.getListFeedUrl().toString() + "?orderby=columnname").toURL();
```

However, this does not work. The feed returned is not sorted at all. Am I missing something? FYI the column I am trying to sort contains email addresses.

EDIT: I just realized that the problem only happens with the old version of Google Spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this happens. The query is performed on the spreadsheet xml and xml tags are in lower case, for example the title of my column in my spreadseet is "Nombre" and the xml `<gsx:nombre>`is not working so instead of using [?orderby=Nombre], use [?orderby=nombre] with a lowercase "n"

[image]

The correct query for this is.

```
URL listFeedUrl = new URI(worksheet.getListFeedUrl().toString() + "?orderby=nombre").toURL();
```